# RTABMAP How to save registered 3D point cloud?

Tags: slam, navigation, turtlebot, rtabmap, rtab

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am building a map with a Kinect 360 and a turtlebot using RTABMAP on Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo.

Everything works fine, I can see the registered 3D point cloud on RTABMAPVIZ or with RVIZ. Now I want to save the 3D Point cloud to .pcd or .ply . I know there is the option in RTABMAPVIZ with File->Export 3D Cloud [descripted here](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/Kinect-mapping#export), but is there any option to do this without using RTABMAPVIZ? Is there any service I can call from the command line or from another node? Or to do this in RVIZ?

Any help would be appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250528/rtabmap-how-to-save-registered-3d-point-cloud?/) by [schrottulk](https://answers.ros.org/users/28444/schrottulk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2016-12-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

It depends on which resolution you need the point cloud. By default, the `/rtabmap/cloud_map` topic (which is a PointCloud2) is voxelized at 5 cm. You can use [pointcloud_to_pcd](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros#pointcloud_to_pcd) to export the point cloud to PCD:

```
$ rosrun pcl_ros pointcloud_to_pcd input:=/rtabmap/cloud_map
```

If rtabmap is not running (e.g., paused), call this to republish the map after being subscribed to `/cloud_map`:

```
$ rosservice call /rtabmap/publish_map 1 1 0
```

See [rtabmap_ros/rtabmap](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#rtabmap) wiki to see parameters related to `/cloud_map`. Unlike rtabmapviz, options are more limited:

```
~cloud_decimation (int, default: 4)
~cloud_max_depth (double, default: 4.0)
~cloud_voxel_size (double, default: 0.05)
```

**EDIT**

In rtabmap version >= 0.11.11, if you have set `subscribe_scan` to `true`, you should explicitly set `Grid/FromDepth` to `true` to assemble 3D Kinect clouds for `/rtabmap/cloud_map`:

```
<node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" name="rtabmap">
   ...
   <param name="Grid/FromDepth" type="string" value="true"/>
</node>
```

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [schrottulk](https://answers.ros.org/users/28444/schrottulk/) on 2016-12-26**:
Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [schrottulk](https://answers.ros.org/users/28444/schrottulk/) on 2017-01-12**:
Hi matlabbe, sorry for bothering you again!
But with cloud_map I only get the 2D projection of the registered 3D Map to the ground.
Is it possible to save the registered 3D Point Cloud from the /rtabmap/mapData Topic to .pcd / .ply directly from the command line without using RTABMAPVIZ ?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2017-01-12**:
updated the answer...

**Comment by [schrottulk](https://answers.ros.org/users/28444/schrottulk/) on 2017-01-14**:
That works perfect! Many Thanks!